# How to verify at runtime if the client WSDL matches the server WSDL?

Tags: java, .net, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am developing a system where .NET (Compact Framework) clients are communicating via SOAP with a Java (AXIS2) server.
As the interface is continuously evolving, I am looking for a way to check at runtime if the client interface completely matches the current interface version of the server.

What is the easiest way to match the interface signature at both ends, without using handcoded version numbers?

Comment: I know you don't want to use versions, but if you use Maven you could use filtering to automate incrementing the version on your server side.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate the expected behavior through automated tests. [soapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) can (among other things) be used to generate a test-suite for you.

Comment: My problem is at runtime: One of many client devices starts up and then needs to check if it is still compatible with the server API. Unit tests won't help me here.